# Getting the file-mode from the FILE struct?

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I have a piece of C code, a function to be specific, which operates on a `FILE*`.

Depending on which mode the `FILE*` was opened with there are certain things I can and cannot do.

Is there any way I can obtain the mode the `FILE*` was opened with?

That `FILE*` is all the info I can rely on, because it is created somewhere else in the program and the actual file-name is long lost before it reaches my function, and this I cannot influence.

I would prefer a portable solution.

Edit: I'm not interested in file-restrictions specifying which users can do what with the file. That is mostly irrelevant as it is dealt with upon file-opening. For this bit of code I only care about the  open-mode.

Comment: Is it on an specific OS? Or you want a portable cross platform solution?

Comment: How could you possibly forget?  Use a variable.

Comment: Thing is that the file is opened in a part of the program which I have no access to modify. So I don't "forget", the info is just not available at the point where my function operates. It's stupid I know, but I can't fix it from my end.

Comment: Do note that on POSIX-ish systems, you can create a file with the file descriptor available for reading and writing, but the permissions of the file on disk could be as restrictive as 000 (no access for anyone who isn't root).  It isn't clear from the question whether you're asking about the 'on disk' mode (set by `chmod()` or `open()` or `creat()`), or whether you're asking about the 'file descriptor mode' (determined by `open()` and modifiable via `fcntl()`).  If you identified what different things you are interested in that you can and cannot do, it would be easier to answer accurately.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: OP clearly asked for "the mode the FILE* was opened with" and not anything about permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On POSIX (and sufficiently similar) systems, `fcntl(fileno(f), F_GETFL)` will return the mode/flags for the open file in the form that would be passed to `open` (not `fopen`). To check whether it was opened read-only, read-write, or write-only, you can do something like:

```
int mode = fcntl(fileno(f), F_GETFL);
switch (mode & O_ACCMODE) {
case O_RDONLY: ...
case O_WRONLY: ...
case O_RDWR: ...
}
```

You can also check for flags like `O_APPEND`, etc.

Comment: Note that even if the file is opened for writing, you can't write at the start of the file if the file is not empty and was opened with O_APPEND.

Comment: @Jonathan It's exactly things like this which is why it's important for me to be able to derive the open-mode of the file

Answer (score -1):

Assuming Linux/Unix:

See [`fstat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat), to get the details of file permissions.

To get the file descriptor us [`fileno()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno) for that function

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question. See my comment on Cong Ma's answer.